# WCF REST Service Template 4.0 "Bad Request"

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to send a large json string to a WCF Service created with the WCF REST Service Template.  If the string is longer 8000 characters I get a "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" error.  I have tried added this to my web config:

```
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="httpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also setup `readerQuotas` if you want to pass large strings:

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="50000" />
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```